# Is there a better way to take a list of addresses on word and seperate them down to single lines

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is there a better way to take a list of addresses on word and separate them down to single line.

I have about 200 addresses to work through and they have to go from this
[image]

To this

[image]

So it can end up being copied like this into excel

[image]

The code I am currently Using is as follows but all that does is uses the replace function to change special formatting characters.

It isn't the cleanest method and if for instance some hasnt used a paragragh break but just a new line then it won't work.

```
    Sub AddressMacro()
'
' AddressMacro Macro
'
'

ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = Not ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View. _
    ShowAll

       Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^l"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With


    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^t"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With


    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^i"
        .Replacement.Text = "^p"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.ShowAll = Not ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View. _
        ShowAll
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about: (replaces)

```
'1) Chr$(9) to Chr$(32)
'2) Chr$(10) to Chr$(13)
'3) Chr$(11) to Chr$(13)
'4) Chr$(13) & Chr$(13) to Chr$(13)
'5) repeat 4 until there are none
'6) Chr$(13) to Chr$(9)
'7) Chr$(133) to Chr$(13)
```

EDIT: Here's what I had in mind:  (It's a lot -- there's a bottomless pit of information on Word VBA -- http://word.mvps.org/faqs/MacrosVBA/index.htm -- good luck.)

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
  Call doReplace(Chr$(9), Chr$(32))
  Call doReplace(Chr$(10), Chr$(13))
  Call doReplace(Chr$(11), Chr$(13))
  Do While doReplace(Chr$(13) & Chr$(13), Chr$(13))
  Loop
  Call doReplace(Chr$(13), Chr$(9))
  Call doReplace(Chr$(133), Chr$(13))
End Sub

Function doReplace(OldText$, NewText$) As Boolean
  With ThisDocument.Content.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = OldText
    .Replacement.Text = NewText
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    doReplace = .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceAll)
  End With
End Function
```

Comment: I am really new to vb with msword, how do i go about implementing this.